# How do compound-list conditionals operate in bash?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I am trying to understand compound lists in the bash environment and what the boolean return value is at the end of the list, but I have not found a complete answer.

The definition of compound lists given [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) gives an example of a compound list in a while loop:

```
while
    # a couple of <newline>s


    # a list
    date && who || ls; cat file
    # a couple of <newline>s


    # another list
    wc file > output & true


do
    # 2 lists
    ls
    cat file
done
```

But I don't quite understand the conditional - does the while loop only execute if all conditions in the list are true? or is it only true if the last condition is true?

A simpler example might be the following:

```
if
    condition1
    condition2
then
    command1
fi
```

Does `command1` execute only if condition2 is true or do both condition1 && condition2 have to be true in order to execute, i.e.:

```
if
    condition1 && \
    condition2
then
    command1
fi
```

Comment: See the section `Lists` in `man bash` for a description of how command lists work.

Comment: If you run `a; b` _outside_ the context of an `if` statement's condition block, `$?` has only the exit status of `b` at the end. That's the same _inside_ an `if` statement as well.

Comment: The status of a list is the status of the last command in the list.

Comment: A list is a sequence of commands separated by `;` or newline. So there's only one command in that list, `true || false`. Its status is `0`. @shellter

Comment: @shellter `false` is never even executed because of short-circuiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is equivalent to:

```
while date && who || ls; cat file; wc file > output & true
do
    ls
    cat file
done
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
foo() {
    date; rc=$?
    if (( rc == 0 ))
    then
       who; rc=$?
    fi

    if (( rc != 0 ))
    then
        ls
    fi
    
    cat file

    wc file > output &

    true
}

while foo
do
    ls
    cat file
done
```

So, given a semi-colon or newline separated list of commands, the final result is entirely the result of the final command in the list and so that function `foo()` will always return an exit status of `success` since the last command in it is `true` and that's just what `true` does.

Time for a quick segue, I think, to address your use of the word "condition" in your question. In C or many other languages when you write:

```
if ( foo ) { do stuff }
```

`foo` is indeed a condition but in shell when you write:

```
if foo; then do stuff; fi
```

`foo` is not a condition, it's a command (or list of commands) that `if` executes and then tests the exit status (still not a condition) from the last command it ran. If that exit status is `success` (`0`) then the part after `then` is executed, otherwise it's `failure` (non-zero) and so the part after `then` is not executed.

You could consider the "condition" in that context to be that the exit status was `success` but neither the command nor it's exit status is itself a "condition". The same applies to `while` and other "conditional constructs" - the thing that comes after `if` or `while` is a command, not a condition, and what is tested is the exit status of the command, also not a condition. The **result** of testing that exit status for success is the condition.

A good example is the command `true` - that is not a condition, it's a command whose only job is to generate the exit status `success` so you can use it in a conditional context like `if true; then` or `while true do`.

You provided these other scripts as examples:

1)

```
if
    condition1
    condition2
then
    command1
fi
```

2. 

```
if
    condition1 && \
    condition2
then
    command1
fi
```

but the word `condition` in those is misleading. What they REALLY are is:

1)

```
if
    command1
    command2
then
    command3
fi
```

2. 

```
if
    command1 && \
    command2
then
    command3
fi
```

That first one:

```
if
    command1
    command2
then
    command3
fi
```

says execute `command1` and discard it's exit status, then execute `command2` and if that exits with status `success` then execute `command3`.

The second one:

```
if
    command1 && \
    command2
then
    command3
fi
```

says execute `command1` and if that exits with status `success` then execute `command2` and if that also exits with status `success` then execute `command3`.

The only really tricky thing in the `&&` and `||` operators is the tendency to think of them as [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator) when they aren't. If:

```
a && b || c
```

were a ternary expression then it'd mean:

```
if a succeeded then
    b
else
    c
fi
```

so `a` will execute followed by either `b` or `c` but never both, but it doesn't mean that in this context, it means:

```
if a succeeded then
    b
fi
if a or b failed then
    c
fi
```

so `a` will execute followed by either `b` or `c` or (`b` then `c` if `b` failed).

One final related bit of information - when you write a C function like:

```
int foo() {
    printf("bar\n");
    return 7;
}
```

and call it as:

```
tmp=foo();
```

you will find that `bar` (the output) is written to `stdout` while `7` (the return code) is stored in `tmp`.

If you write similar-looking shell:

```
foo() {
    printf "bar\n"
    return 7
}

tmp=$(foo)
```

you will find that `bar` is stored in `tmp` while `7` is stored in the builtin variable `$?` (which holds the exit status of the last command ran) and nothing is written to `stdout`. So just keep in mind that:

- `return` actually sets the exit status for a function, just like
  `exit` sets it for a script.
- `var=$(command)` stores the output of the command (including functions) in `var`, not the exit status set by `return` or `exit`.
- The exit status set by `return` from a function or `exit` from a script is stored in `$?`.

That is why in the code I wrote at the start of this answer you will see:

```
    date; rc=$?
    if (( rc == 0 ))
    then
```

I'm saving the exit status from `date` in a variable (because I also need it again later in the script) and then `if` is executing the arithmetic command `((...))` which is then comparing the contents of `rc` to the number `0` (the `success` exit status) and if they match then that arithmetic command exits with status `success` and then whatever command comes after `then` gets executed.

Hope that helps and I hope the discussion of commands, exit status (success or fail) and conditions (true or false) above makes things a bit clearer and doesn't add to your confusion.

Comment: `return true` isn't valid, though `return 0` would make the point.

Comment: @chepner fixed thanks.

Comment: `if $rc`? Unless you have a command named `0` or `1`, what's the meaning there? Perhaps you want `if (( rc == 0 ))` everywhere `if $rc` is currently written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy indeed, fixed thanks.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the discussion, this answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

> How do compound-list conditionals operate in bash?

They just execute stuff, like outside a compound-list. It's a normal list of commands, like the ones you type in terminal. They operate completely normally, just like you would type them out in a terminal and check `echo $?` after typing them out.

> does the while loop only execute if all conditions in the list are true? or is it only true if the last condition is true?

There is only one single "condition". The condition is, the while loop body executes if the compound-list exits with zero exit status.

The exit status of a compound-list is the exit status of the last command executed.

The last command of `anything bla bla & true` is `true`. The exit status of `true` is zero.

> Does command1 execute only if condition2 is true or do both condition1 && condition2 have to be true in order to execute

Only if the command `condition2` exits with zero exit status. The exit status of the command `condition1` is ignored.

I do not think I agree with calling them "conditions". These are normal, regular commands, like anywhere else.

Note: "true" and "false" does not mean "success" and "failure". A non-zero number is "true", but zero exit status is "success". For example, the command `(( 1 + 1 ))` evaluates `1 + 1` to true and exits with success.